# Is there a way to disable a button based on the time of day

Tags: flutter, time, flutter-dependencies

So essentially I want to disable a checkout button until 2pm but can't seem to figure out how to do it and where to place the if statement logic.

Answer (score 0):

The following button will remain disabled between 1am and 3am.

```
RaisedButton(
      onPressed: (DateTime.now().hour >= 1 && DateTime.now().hour <= 3) ? null : () => whatToDoOnPressed,
      child: Text('Button text')
    );
```

The following button will remain disabled till 2pm

```
RaisedButton(
      onPressed: (DateTime.now().hour < 14) ? null : () => whatToDoOnPressed,
      child: Text('Button text')
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your onTap or onPressed

```
onTap: (){
    // in this way everytime it press it will check the time, and not only one time on build!
    if (DateTime.now().hour < 14) return; 
    else checkout();
},
```

And you maybe want to do the same to the color of the button(without repeating the code ;P)

But, a remark:
The time is the local time! So, probably not the one of your server!